# Do-while doesn't loop back

Tags: java, loops, do-while

So I'm working on a that involves binary conversion etc. But my problem here is that I can't seem to make the do-while statement in my code to loopback whenever the catch block finishes executing. Here's my code.

```
System.out.println("This program converts a binary value to its decimal counterpart.\n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean invalidInput = true;

    do {

        try {
            System.out.print("(>) Enter the value to be converted: ");
            String numberToConvert = input.nextLine();
            long converted = Long.parseLong(numberToConvert, 2);
            System.out.println("(>) Decimal value of " + numberToConvert + " is : " + converted + "\n");
            invalidInput = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("(!) Entered value is non binary, please try again.\n");
            input.next();
        }

    } while (invalidInput);
```

Comment: Remove the `input.next();` from your catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove input.next() from catch block and then try :-

```
    System.out.println("This program converts a binary value to its decimal counterpart.\n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean invalidInput = true;

    do {

        try {
            System.out.print("(>) Enter the value to be converted: ");
            String numberToConvert = input.nextLine();
            long converted = Long.parseLong(numberToConvert, 2);
            System.out.println("(>) Decimal value of " + numberToConvert + " is : " + converted + "\n");
            invalidInput = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("(!) Entered value is non binary, please try again.\n");
        }

    } while (invalidInput);
```